# Static image loading issue in react-native

Tags: react-native, clojurescript

Has anyone encountered static image loading issue in react-native with clojurescript for ios with lein-figwheel.We have tried builds with lein prod-build, lein advanced-build.
Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: I haven't used it but there might be a problem with your code. usually I check the repo for open issue (or create one if think I am using it fine). If you think you might be doing wrong then it is always better to share your code snippet :)

Comment: It would be better if told us how does this issue manifest itself.